# Trying to modify an sqlite3 insert to return the PK. Wasn't sure how to do it with sqlite3 specifically

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I was trying to insert into a table some data, but I wasn't sure what flag allows me to return the primary key. I believe I recall MSSQL using RETURNING, and some others tack on RETURNS at the end.

could someone help out with the appending of it?

I'm trying to return TABLEA.a, and my query and design would look something like this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("...",&db);
std::string query;
query = "insert into TABLEA (b,c,d,e) values (@b,\"@c\",@d,@e);"; 
            //^--this needs to be modified.
sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), 01, &sqlstmt, 0);
sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
int ID;
ID = sqlite3_column_integer(sqlstmt,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) ?

Comment: i have not.  I can test it though to see what occurs.

Comment: YEs, it works.  I had to read up on it.  If there is a NON INT PK it will return the UNIQUE ROW ID.   If there is a INT PK, it will return that.  Thanks a lot Thesimm